# Perforce command line only showing local users/changelists/workspaces, but P4V shows all

Tags: perforce

We are using P4 for free with two users. In the P4V admin gui I can see both myself and my partner as users, and in the P4V gui I can see all workspaces (clients) and all changelists (both mine and my partner's). From the command line, 'p4 users' only shows me, 'p4 clients' only shows my local workspace, etc. Is there some mode, environment setting, or special directory from which I have to use the p4 command line to see those global objects? I believe I am a p4 superuser (since I read this is the default on installation and we didn't change anything). I'm obviously missing something very basic about the relationship between p4 command line and P4V.

The reason I need to use the command line is to delete an old client workspace (used on a different machine) that has an empty changelist associated with it. I therefore need to use 'p4 client -d -f old-workspace-name' from the command line. But when I do it tells me client 'old-workspace-name' doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

D'oh! I had a setup with two p4 servers (one that I had set up briefly as an experiment and forgot about). My gui was pointing to the real one and my command line was pointing to the experimental one. They both had a client with a certain name, so I was confusing them for being the same. Hope this helps someone else who makes the same mistake.